# How does a 8 bit register bank hold 8 regsiters of 8 bits each?

Tags: microcontroller, ram, 8051, register

In `8051`, there are 128 bytes of `RAM`. Of which, 32 are set aside for registers in the form of banks, 8 registers to each bank. Each bank is addressed from say `00` to `07`, `08` to `0F`, etc, that is, occupying 8  bits each, with each but corresponding to a register, thus 8 registers in each bank.

How can this be possible, when the registers themselves occupy 8 bits? Won't each bank occupy 8*8 = 64 bits instead of 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each address holds 8 bits. 32 addresses are set aside as registers, 8 bits each.  Each register bank has 8 registers in it.  Each register bank is 64 bits/8 bytes. 96 addresses are as RAM.  96+32 = 128 Bytes total.  It's just that the first 32 bytes are registers rather than RAM.  I think you may be getting bits mixed up with bytes.

Comment: Oh ho, each register occupies 1 byte, so 8 registers mean 8 bytes, or 1 bank. That's dumb of me..Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know if any 8051-architecture chips actually implement the first 32 bytes as registers different from the remaining 96/224, or does "ADD Rn" simply do a normal RAM read from address "000bbnnn"?